# How to install rubber on macOS?

Tags: macos, rubber

Rubber seems to be available on various Linux repositories but not on macOS. What is the recommended way of installing rubber on macOS? Could a package be made available on Homebrew?

Comment: if you follow these instructions, you should be fine:
http://macappstore.org/rubber/

Comment: Unfortunately, rubber seems to be unavailable on Homebrew.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: Homebrew does not host rubber anymore. Try the Github instructions instead.

---

How to "Install rubber on Mac OSX" (source found here, last accessed 02.04.2019, 1426h UTC: http://macappstore.org/rubber/ )

Installation Guide taken in full from website. I did not write, edit or test any instruction beforehand. Use with caution and at own risk:

> Install the App
>
> ```
> 1.) Press Command+Space and type Terminal and press enter/return key.
> 2.) Run in Terminal app:
> ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null
>
> and press enter/return key.
> If the screen prompts you to enter a password, please enter your Mac's user password to continue. When you type the password, it won't be displayed on screen, but the system would accept it. So just type your password and press ENTER/RETURN key. Then wait for the command to finish.
> 3.) Run:
>  brew install rubber
> ```
>
> Done! You can now use rubber.

Edit2:

Found an alternative instruction set on github (source found here, last accessed 02.04.2019, 1440H UTC: https://github.com/oracleyue/rubber ).

> Installation
>
> Running Rubber just requires Python version 2.6 or newer.  Of course
>   it won't be of much use without a working LaTeX environment (Rubber is
>   known to work on TeXLive and VTeX on various flavors of Unix including
>   Darwin and Cygwin, any feedback is welcome about other systems).
>
> For compilation, you will need the Python Distutils, which are usually
>   included in development packages (in Debian, this is the python-dev
>   package).  To build the documentation, you need texinfo (Debian
>   package: texinfo).
>
> To compile and install Rubber, just follow the usual procedure:

```
# python2 setup.py --help
# python2 setup.py install
# python2 setup.py clean --all
```

For further instructions, see the source.

Comment: Rubber was deleted from Homebrew a few years ago, probably due to lack of use; theoretically it could likely be brought back.

Comment: It seems like https://github.com/oracleyue/rubber (latest commit 2018-03-08) is an unmaintained fork of the main repository at https://launchpad.net/rubber/ (latest commit 2019-01-06).

Comment: @EddieSchoute since it's a fork, I have no clue, how it differs from the original. I currently don't run a *nix based system, so testing or researching any deeper on this topic is unfeasible for me. if you find an answer, that works for you, based on what I found in 5 minutes of googling, you're welcome to post it.

Comment: On manual install if you see *makeinfo* errors e.g. "Next field of node 'Non UTF-8 sources' not pointed to" you'll need to install an upgraded version using `brew install texinfo` and put it in your PATH (only needed for install).